# bidirectional belongs_to (one polymorphic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have two kinds of classes, one of which belongs_to the other kind, and one of which polymorphically belongs to the other kind.

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reference, :polymorphic => true
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :term
end

class Career < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :term
end
```

The relationships are belongs_to because I want fast access in both directions.  I'm under the impression that the `has_one` relationship would be slower because you would have to query the opposite table to search for a matching `_id`.

Right now, when I create a course `c`, I run an after_save method which creates a term `t` such that `c.term = t` and `t.reference = c`.  This seems like kind of a hack though... is there any way to automatically tell rails that this relationship exists and that setting `c.term = t` should automatically make `t.reference = c`?

I know that with polymorphic associations you can specify the `:as` attribute (see the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)), but it looks like this doesn't work for belongs_to.

```
  class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

    def attachable_type=(sType)
       super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
    end
  end

  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    # because we store "Post" in attachable_type now :dependent => :destroy will work
    has_many :assets, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're not really meant to do bi-directional `belongs_to` associations. As such, when you add polymorphicality (is that really a word?) into the equation, it will break.

> The relationships are belongs_to because I want fast access in both directions. I'm under the impression that the has_one relationship would be slower because you would have to query the opposite table to search for a matching _id.

I don't see why you'd want to do this. If you're really concerned with speed, you can simply index the foreign_key column(s) on the table that `belongs_to`. The speed difference should be negligible.

Comment: hmm, okay, point taken.  adding indexes and wiping the bidirectional `belongs_to` associations.  thanks.